# page redirection to exact url from login page

Tags: php, drupal, redirect, drupal-6

Thanks In advance.
I was using drupal 6 version. If i am not logged in and in some url for ex : www.mysite.com/books/add-book .. it was taking me to login page . because only logged in users only can post a book.

```
$dest = drupal_get_destination();
drupal_goto('user/register', $dest);
```

Once it redirects to register page and after logged in it has to take me to exact page like www.mysite.com/books/add-book.. But now it was taking to front page..

Please suggest me how to redirect to exact page from loggin..

Answer (score 1):

The [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module may help you do that. You can adjust its configuration to redirect to coming page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar to redirect users once they've changed the interface language. I'm not using Dupral but the php behind should work for you as well.

In every controller of my site I set a session variable with the current page. If the user change the interface's language I redirect to a controller to do so, and then redirect to the page set in the session.

Just check if the variable is set after login and then redirect to it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. But in drupal some modules are interfaced... So please suggest me how to proceed in drupal